# MySQLNonTransientConnectionException/CommunicationsException when validation is true in domain.xml?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, glassfish, connection-pooling

Setup: Glassfish 3x, Java EE, EclipseLink.

jdbc connection pool config (from domain.xml):

```
<jdbc-connection-pool validation-table-name="dummy" pool-resize-quantity="5" max-pool-size="300" datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource" wrap-jdbc-objects="false" res-type="javax.sql.XADataSource" steady-pool-size="25" name="mysql_bazaarify_rootPool" is-connection-validation-required="true" non-transactional-connections="true" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="60">
      <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://demodb.mydb.com:3306/database?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;useUnicode=yes"></property>
```

Getting CommunicationsException infrequently for different queries.
I have configured for connections to be validated before use with 60 seconds of validity.
wait_time on sql server is 8 hours.

Still I am seeing below error in my logs (~50 times a day)
Exception Trace:

```
Internal Exception: 
    com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
    Error Code: 0
    ....
    Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: 
    The last packet successfully received from the server was 56,688,227 milliseconds ago.  
    The last packet sent successfully to the server was 56,688,227 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. 
    You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, 
    increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
    ....
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3832)
        ... 140 more
```

My question is, when I have set for connection to be validated (every 60 seconds), is it possible that I get a stale/broken connection from connection pool which says that the last communication with mysql was (>60seconds) ago?

Shouldn't the connection be validated until a healthy one is returned from the pool? Are these exceptions normal with the settings I have configured?

P.S.
I observed that in all such failures, the milliseconds ago value reported is always >8 hours. Does that help deduce anything?

Comment: You may want to consider recycling connections earlier (limiting the max age of a connection in the connection pool config). That connection was - apparently - unused for nearly 16 hours. Likely it was closed by MySQL due to a max connection lifetime setting on the server. It is also an indication that your current configuration is probably wildly oversized.

Comment: thanks Mark. I can tinker with idle timeout. But my question is, how is it possible to have this exception with 16 hours when i have set connection validation (60 seconds).

Comment: That setting has a bit of a weird name, and I'm unsure what it exactly does. However it can also be read that a connection will be check at most once every 60 seconds (that can be very relevant for connections that get checked out and in often). So not checking until the connection is really needed would also fulfill that requirement. Checking a connection every 60 seconds can be wasteful if the connection won't be used anyway.

Comment: I get burst requests during specific intervals. hence, i have to keep relaxed settings for pool. I understand I should keep idle timeout (expiry for connections), but I still don't understand why would a connection fail, when I have specified validation.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just an exception logged for a connection that was expunged because it failed the validation check? Otherwise you are probably checking out a connection and continue using it without ever returning it to the pool.

Comment: if it had failed a validation check(select query on dummy table), then a next connection would have been allocated and the request wouldn't have failed. That's why this is giving me headaches.

Comment: if this was a connection leak scenario, then that wouldn't explain the 16hrs.